# How to get packet inbound and outbound stats for each interface in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

I am looking for stats such as:

1. total packets received
2. total inbound packets dropped
3. total outbound packets dropped etc.

Is there any Windows API for this?

Comment: You want to monitor packet inbound and outbound ?

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan I want to obtain information about packet inbound and outbound for every interface.

Comment: You want to implement wireshark like software in c++

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan no no. I just want to obtain information about the stats.

Comment: then use wireshark to do that ..

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan My question isn't about using Wireshark. I want to retrieve this information using C++ on Windows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138152/discussion-between-ankur-jyoti-phukan-and-black-dragon).